# Fluid is not touching container

Tags: render, simulation, blender

I'm trying to create a fluid simulation on blender 2.92 but after the bake of the fluid, this one is not laying on the floor. It's floating at around 10cm above and also, it stays at 10cm from the walls.

[Space between fluid and floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Bbw.png)

[Space between fluid and walls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cxn8.jpg)

[Low res render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSLdf.png)

Does anybody know what I'm setting wrong ? The obstacle is inside a cube which has a solidify modifier applied and set up as Effector / Collision.

Any help will be appreciated

Did

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without having much to look at other than what you had provided, it's the resolution of your domain. When you look at your domain box, there should be a small "cube" in the corner. If you move the cube down under your floor to where the top of the cube is touching the floor, this will fix the gap between the floor and water. Just keep in mind, when you increase that resolution, that cube will get smaller. Meaning, you will need to adjust the position of it yet again. For the walls, you will need to widen your domain until the side of the cube is on the outside of the wall.

Think of the cube as a "safety boundary/perimeter" or something like that. Hopefully that all makes sense?

Comment: The resolution of my domain is 256 and the cube symbolizing this division is far below the floor (top of the small cube around 70cm below). The domain is large enough (1.5 meters larger than the room on each side).

I've checked that the "room" has no non-manifold vertices nor edges...

Comment: Could you maybe share a screenshot of your domain/effector? Or share your file? My only other suggestion without looking at it would be making sure your effector is set up correctly for the walls and floor. And if you haven't already, apply the size to the walls/floor. Make sure to clear your cache and re-bake it too

Comment: You may find the .blend file here [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mhx2shCGQXzfjRSUjdTDtgLdMOp2mXIG/view?usp=sharing](.blend file).

Comment: I've applied scale and rotations to the room (because of the UV and the materials)

Comment: I've just seen that the room effector is set up "is planar" and I'm wondering if this is suitable for a non-plan object. I've started a bake without this.

Comment: I think I've found the issue with this "is planar" set on the non-planar room which is a cube with solidifier applied. Thanks for your help. The discussion pushed me to make a step back and stop focusing on the settings of the domain (resolution, etc.)

Comment: Alright, that's good news then! Glad I could help!